# Show $\mathbb{C}P^n$ is a $2n-$manifold [in singular homology theory]

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

There is a Theorem in the book that says:

**The space $\mathbb{C}P^n$ is CW complex of dimension $2n$.**

I wonder some questions:

Is there any Theorem or result that if a space has CW complex structure, then it is a manifold?

Furthermore, to prove that it is of dimension $2n$, can one use a homology group of it? Is there any relation between dimension and homology group?

---

PS. Please do not answer using tools in Differential Geometry or Differential Topology.

Comment: I would say that this is not an a priori statement. For example for compact four manifolds the existence of a CW-complex structure is open. See http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Questions_about_surgery_theory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, having a CW complex structure is absolutely not enough to be a manifold. Being a CW complex is very easy, being a manifold is hard. Take the wedge sum of two circles $S^1 \vee S^1$ for example: it's a CW complex, but not a manifold.

If a space $M$ is a compact manifold without boundary, then you can read its dimension using singular homology: it is the greatest integer $n$ such that $H_n(M;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ is nonzero (and then it will be equal to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$). But this requires 1/ to know that $M$ is a manifold (without boundary) and 2/ to know that it is compact. Indeed, look at the homology of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and try to read its dimension there.

In the previous paragraph, the word "dimension" referred to the dimension of a manifold: the dimension of $M$ is the number $n$ such that $M$ is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. The dimension of a CW complex is something else: it is the maximum dimension of the cells of the CW complex. If $X$ is a CW complex and you know it's a manifold, then the two notions agree, but in general you can talk about the dimension of a CW complex without knowing that its a manifold and vice-versa.

For your particular problem, the most straight-forward way is simply to give an explicit CW decomposition of $\mathbb{CP}^n$. This will prove that it's a CW complex, and since you will only have used cell of dimension $\le 2n$ it will prove it has dimension $2n$. To prove that it is a manifold is a different question altogether.

Comment: Oh I see. The problem is to prove that it is a manifold. I just wonder whether I can use above theorem of CW complex. So to prove that it is a manifold, is it enough that I show that a quotient map $S^{2n+1}\to S^{2n+1}/~$ is continuous?

Comment: @ChenMLing No, this is not enough. A quotient map is always continuous, by definition of the quotient topology...

Comment: So it has nothing to do with the quotient map? Hmm.. Then how to show that it is a manifold using Algebraic Topology tools (without using chart)?

Comment: @ChenMLing Using concrete charts is the most straight-forward way. It is a good exercise, too.

Comment: Yes, indeed using chart is straight forward, I have learnt it. But since this question arose in Homology section, I just wonder what Algebraic topological tools I can use :)

Comment: @ChenMLing Homology isn't really designed for this. You can often tell if a space is *not* a manifold using homology, but rarely the reverse...

Comment: How can I tell that a space is not a manifold using homology? Is that the case where we cannot find greatest integer $n$ such that the $n-$th homology group is not trivial?

Comment: @ChenMLing Yes, for example. You also have Poincaré duality and so on.

Comment: Oh OK. Thanks so much for willing to discuss with me @NajibIdrissi :)